# How can I typeset and annotate bilingual poetry?

Tags: typography, annotations, poetry

I need to translate into English and annotate Latin poetry (specifically Horace's satires, which I will copy and paste from [here](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/horace/serm1.shtml)), and then annotate the **Latin**.

Ideally I would have to make minimal to no changes to the Latin I copy and paste in for typesetting purposes (i.e. appending `//` after every line).  If it is possible, I would like to write the actual text of the annotations in the source code outside of the text of the Latin, but this is non-essential. I need to be able to annotate a word, phrase, and preferably (although this is not an absolute requirement) a series of non-consecutive letters, words or phrases. The annotations, which are in English, range from about a sentence in length to a small paragraph.

If it is possible I would like to set the poetry out in columns - i.e. Latin on one side, and English on the other, with lines that more or less line up, but I am not fussed about where the annotations go, although it would be better if they were on the same page as the text they annotate and if there were some sort of visual link between the annotation and the text annotated (like a line). I would guess that there are 1-3 annotations on a given line, although that number occasionally is higher.

I've looked at various solutions for two columns of text, but I'm stuck on annotations that don't require a horrendous amount of markup within the text annotated, and even then I'm not sure about how to do annotations well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might be interested in the `poemscol` or the `reledmac` packages.

Comment: `reledmac` has a sister called `reledpar` that can take care of the parallel setup. They are both preinstalled with texlive and come -- apart from the documentaion as such -- with a lot of instructive example files. They will probably get you going more quickly.

Comment: You might additionally use `babel` for the bilingual text, but English and Latin might be similar enough for it not to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it, which requires some steps of preparations:

- using a certain editor, `TexMaker` here
- using package `paracol`
- using some translation, here [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com) for simplicity
- using some scripting language, `Perl` here

#### Conflicting requirements

As the OP stated, there is a conflict:

- on one hand s/he needs to use markup (Latex)
- however, this makes Latex code hard to read quickly
- so on the other hand introducing further markings later in the pdf generated would be nicer (NOT-Latex)

The exact solution is to provide both: Latex AND NOT-Latex.

A way to achieve this is to `separate requirements in space`:

- use Latex HERE
- AND
- use NOT-Latex THERE
- i.e. have both

I'm not aware of some software which allows going back and forth between Latex (.tex) and Not-Latex (e.g. pdf), so I had a look at editors.

#### Editor

I tried `Lyx` for that purpose, but it doesn't convince me:

- read-ability isn't much better
- the Latex code exported is ... you better don't want that.

`TexMaker` is an alternative:

- in one window you enter code
- in a second window it displays the compiled result
- there you can point and CTRL+click to go to the associated code line (however, this doesn't always work for a reason)

Using `TexMaker without the CTRL+click` feature is also possible, as a bypass:

- introduce (temporarily) some markings
- which are easy to spot in both the .pdf and .tex
- so navigation is easier to do

Below I used this bypass, which you can augment with some `versioning` package, i.e. showing them for `draft`, but removed in `final` versions.

#### Package paracol

Package `paracol` seems to be very useful for this poetry analysis and annotation task. It allows you to:

- have several columns
- switch amongst them as you go
- synchronize them vertically as needed.

After some experimentation it seems to be best to intermix linewise Latin text and the English translation. Of course you can also consider to have blocks of, say, 5 lines to do manual rearrangements later.

So as a starting point this frame provides 4 columns `Annotation[0]-Latin[1]-Annotation[2]-English[3]` in A3 landscape format for demonstration.

[image: res1]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{paracol}{4}
    Annotations
    \switchcolumn[1]
    Latin
    \switchcolumn[2]
    Annotations
    \switchcolumn[3]
    English
% >>> intermix will go here <<<
 \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

#### Translation

For the script, which will mix both languages line by line, I use two simple text files, where the English translation comes from google as stated above for simplicity. Make sure, both have the same (matching) number of lines.

lat.txt:

```
Qui fit, Maecenas, ut nemo, quam sibi sortem
seu ratio dederit seu fors obiecerit, illa
contentus vivat, laudet diversa sequentis?
...
```

en.txt:

```
Who becomes, Maecenas, like no one, but his lot
either reason will give, or chance will object, she
He lives contentedly, praises the different following?
...
```

#### Scripting

With the scripting language of your choice, create the mix of lines you find useful, e.g. linewise here:

mix.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
use warnings;

# ~~~ texts ~~~~~~~~~~~
my $fl="lat.txt";
my $fe="en.txt";

# ~~~ read them ~~~~~
open my $L, '<', $fl or die "can't open $fl\n";
open my $E, '<', $fe or die "can't open $fe\n";
my @L = <$L>;
my @E = <$E>;

# ~~~ same length ? ~~~
if(scalar(@L) != scalar(@E)) {
    print "Different numer of lines in both files. EXIT\n" ;
    exit;
}

# ~~~ creating output ~~~~
my $s = "";

for(my $i=0; $i < scalar(@L); $i++) {
    $s .= "\\switchcolumn[1]*\n" ;
    chomp($L[$i]);
    $s .= $L[$i] . "\\\\\n";
    $s .= "\\switchcolumn[3]\n" ;
    chomp($E[$i]);
    $s .= $E[$i] . "\\\\\n";
}

print $s;
```

which results in:

```
\switchcolumn[1]*
Qui fit, Maecenas, ut nemo, quam sibi sortem\\
\switchcolumn[3]
Who becomes, Maecenas, like no one, but his lot\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
seu ratio dederit seu fors obiecerit, illa\\
\switchcolumn[3]
either reason will give, or chance will object, she\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
contentus vivat, laudet diversa sequentis?\\
\switchcolumn[3]
He lives contentedly, praises the different following?\\
...
```

after calling from the command line:

```
>mix.pl > mix.txt
```

As you can see, the Latin column ([1](https://translate.google.com)) synchronizes all stuff vertically, line by line, via `\switchcolumn[1]*`.

Copy that (mix.txt) into your frame and start refining the code.

#### After a while ...

the code might produce the following:

[image: res2]

Some remarks.

1. the `\newcommand`s provide some macros for highlighting or changing style of text. E.g. with `TexMaker` you can enter those as `user defined commands` to simplify editing. E.g. you can highlight a phrase, mark them e.g. as EMPHASIZED from the icon menue, and change `emph` into `hla` manually to `highlight` it instead etc.
2. Remember that sometimes you need a second compile run, e.g. for the tikzmarks to show correctly.
3. To put a verbal annotation in column 0 or 2, just put before the next synchronizsation:

```
\switchcolumn[1]*
miles ait, multo iam fractus membra labore;               5\\
\switchcolumn[3]
said the soldier, whose limbs had already been much broken by exertion; 5\\
% ~~~ here's a remark ~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[0]
watch out!
```

4. Using tikzmark is a bit tricky. I put two of them, `t1` and `t2`. It looks like you have to put the `tikzpicture` I used very close to the second mark. There are more options, see the tikzmark manual.

```
% ~~~ let's put a tickmark here ~~~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[1]*
'o fortunati mercatores' gravis annis\tikzmark{t1}\\
...
% ~~~ let's put an other tickmark here ~~~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[1]*
contra mercator navim iactantibus Austris:\tikzmark{t2}
% ~~~ insert the required drawing ~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[draw=red,->,thick] ([xshift=5mm]pic cs:t1) to[out=0,in=45] node[blue,anchor=west,pos=.65] {some remark}([xshift=5mm]pic cs:t2);
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
```

#### "Final" code

As you can see I started to put some marks in the code, like  `% ... 5 ...` to find line #5 in the .tex file. As google appended each 5th line number switching between the pdf-view (showing some numbers) and the code window is quite possible.

Sooner or later you will start changing e.g. indenting style a little bit more to better follow what's going on, and perhaps instruct the script already to do so, like:

```
\switchcolumn[1]*
'o fortunati mercatores' gravis annis\tikzmark{t1}\\
   \switchcolumn[3]
   'O fortunate merchants' in heavy years\\
```

`In summary`, using Latex you can't hinder a kind of 'littering' your code with all kinds of markups. However, with the (bypass) means I lined out it's quite close to the intended exact solution described in the beginning.

"Final":

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
% ~~~ using tikzmark ~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
% ~~~ for highlighting ~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}

% ~~~ nicer colors: see also color model and names in xcolor manual
%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615774/where-to-definecolor
\definecolor{es-bg}{HTML}{E7EDF4}% (cornflower light blue ...)


% ~~~ highlighting ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\hly[1]{\sethlcolor{yellow}\hl{#1}}
\newcommand\hlc[1]{\sethlcolor{es-bg}\hl{#1}}
\newcommand\hlg[1]{\sethlcolor{green}\hl{#1}}
\newcommand\hll[1]{\sethlcolor{lime}\hl{#1}}

% ~~~ text in colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\tr[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\tru[1]{\textcolor{red}{\underline{#1}}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\tikzset{>={Latex}} % for better arrow tip

 \begin{paracol}{4}
    \textbf{Annotations}
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \textbf{Latin}
    \switchcolumn[2]
    \textbf{Annotations}
    \switchcolumn[3]
    \textbf{English}

% ... 1 ...
 \switchcolumn[1]*
Qui fit, \hly{Maecenas}, ut nemo, quam sibi sortem\\
\switchcolumn[3]
Who becomes, Maecenas, like no one, but his lot\\
% ~~~ let's put a sentence here ~~~
\switchcolumn[0]
Here the whole poem starts with an opening sentence. And it won't stop. Which means, it will continue for a while.

\switchcolumn[1]*
seu \hlc{r}atio \hlc{ded}erit seu fors obie\hlc{cerit}, illa\\
\switchcolumn[3]
either reason will give, or chance will object, she\\
\switchcolumn[2]
just \tr{watch} \hly{this highlight}

\switchcolumn[1]*
contentus \tru{vivat, laudet} diversa sequentis?\\
\switchcolumn[3]
He lives contentedly, praises the different following?\\
% ~~~ let's put a tickmark here ~~~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[1]*
'o fortunati mercatores' gravis annis\tikzmark{t1}\\
\switchcolumn[3]
'O fortunate merchants' in heavy years\\

% ... 5 ...
\switchcolumn[1]*
miles ait, multo iam fractus membra labore;               5\\
\switchcolumn[3]
said the soldier, whose limbs had already been much broken by exertion; 5\\
% ~~~ here's a remark ~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[0]
watch out!

% ~~~ let's put an other tickmark here ~~~~~~~~~
\switchcolumn[1]*
contra mercator navim iactantibus Austris:\tikzmark{t2}
% ~~~ insert the required drawing ~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[draw=red,->,thick] ([xshift=5mm]pic cs:t1) to[out=0,in=45] node[blue,anchor=west,pos=.65] {some remark}([xshift=5mm]pic cs:t2);
 \end{tikzpicture}\\
\switchcolumn[3]
against the merchant ship of the South:\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
\hlg{'militia est potior. quid enim?} concurritur: horae\\
\switchcolumn[3]
The war is more important. What is? it is run: hours\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
momento cita mors venit aut victoria laeta.'\\
\switchcolumn[3]
at the moment mentioned comes death or happy victory.'\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
agricolam lau\hll{dat} iuris legum\hll{que} peritus,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
the farmer is praised by the expert in law and law,\\

% ... 10 ...
\switchcolumn[1]*
sub galli cantum consultor ubi ostia pulsat;               10\\
\switchcolumn[3]
under the rooster's song, the counselor knocks at the door; 10\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
ille, datis vadibus qui rure extractus in urbem est,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
he, having been drawn from the countryside into the city,\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
solos felicis viventis clamat in urbe.\\
\switchcolumn[3]
He cries out for the happy living alone in the city.\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
cetera de genere hoc—adeo sunt multa—loquacem\\
\switchcolumn[3]
the rest of this kind—and there are many—is eloquent\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
delassare valent Fabium. ne te morer, audi,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
they are able to let down the Fabius. don't let me die, listen\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
quo rem deducam. si quis deus 'en ego' dicat               15\\
\switchcolumn[3]
by which I will conclude the matter. if any god says 'en ego' 15\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
'iam faciam quod voltis: eris tu, qui modo miles,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
I will do what you wish: it will be you who are just a soldier\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
mercator; tu, consultus modo, rusticus: hinc vos,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
merchant; you, just a counselor, a rustic: hence you,\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
vos hinc mutatis discedite partibus. eia,\\
\switchcolumn[3]
you, having changed from here, leave the parties. yes\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
quid statis?' nolint. atqui licet esse beatis.\\
\switchcolumn[3]
what are you standing for?' they don't want but it is permissible to be happy.\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
quid causae est, merito quin illis Iuppiter ambas               20\\
\switchcolumn[3]
what is the cause, by virtue of Jupiter having them both 20\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
iratus buccas inflet neque se fore posthac\\
\switchcolumn[3]
He blew his lips in anger, and said that he would not be hereafter\\
\switchcolumn[1]*
tam facilem dicat, votis ut praebeat aurem?\\
\switchcolumn[3]
so easy to say, do you wish that he would lend an ear?\\

 \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```